# Change event triggers in safari when files property is updated dynamically

Tags: input, safari, uploader

I am creating a custom uploader such that user can drag and drop files in to the custom drop area instead of uploader element. In order to achieve this, I need to update the files property of the Uploader by capturing the drop event. When doing so, change event is triggered for Safari browser alone and the same does not occur in the remaining browsers (Chrome, Edge and FireFox).

It can be replicated in the below sample.

Sample Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qeduax?file=index.js.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.